# My car is more noisy, is it something to worry about?

Tags: engine, noise, car

My Altima is 10 years old and I am the only owner. Lately it's more noisy like engine noise when I am on high way. I am rather used to it but if I have new passenger, they definitely tell me why is my car that noisy.

I am not sure why is it noisy but lately my car does eat more oil too and now I change oil/filter ahead of schedule because it's almost empty by the schedule time.

This noise I am talking about is like engine noise, the car is just loud.

Could this indicate the car can break down? Should I change anything to fix it?

It's an old car now so I don't want to spend a lot of money on it but should I make it priority to replace it? I was hoping to replace in a year or two otherwise.

Comment: Does your coolant temperature stay slightly below where it was before the noise started? Your fan could be running without need.

Answer (score 3):

The noise could be almost anything but the most concerning thing to me is the oil usage.  It sounds like you have a problem which may or may not be related to the noise.  Get it checked by a mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's something to worry about. Increased noise is often from cracked or rotten exhaust components. One important function of the exhaust system is to duct exhaust, which is not good for you, to the rear of the car so you don't breathe it. If the exhaust system isn't sound you'll get increased noise and you and your passengers could be breathing in toxic fumes.

The oil problem doesn't sound related, although it could be a symptom of something causing noise, however you really should have that looked at too.

Comment: It could be due to exhaust because it seems to have come up after I did repairs in exhaust system. The technician was sharp, he fixed it hole with welding instead of asking me to replace the whole part. But maybe its not done quite right. I did follow up with him and he checked and said there are no leaks.